# Need a Barcode Scanning device that call Rest Api Method

Tags: barcode

I need a Barcode Scanning Device that reads code of an item and make callback to Rest Api Methods that i configure.

Any one have idea about it ?

## **Scenario:**

The concept behind is , we have maintain our inventory stock in three difference location , so when a person pick any item from Location 1 to Location 2 , they simply scan that item and the device will hit Rest Api Method that makes Item Adjustment in Database

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?